# linux ssh error while connecting to the host

Tags: networking, ssh

I lately bought a host on godaddy, everything was working well until i started getting bothered to always have input the password and decided to use id_rsa to be able to get authenticated automatically. So I followed a tutorial on how to generate the `rsa 2048`, So I removed all files residing in the .ssh directory and I generated the Key and when I came to the fact i had to `ssh-copy-id` it has disconnected me with this error `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

since that day I can't connect anymore to my remote host leaving me with this error :

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <host> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jasha/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

the last 24 hours I am looking for a solution uselessly, please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase an SSL certificate from GoDaddy and then read tutorials on how to install it for your particular server? It seems like you altogether did not install the SSL certificate properly.

Comment: I didn't purchase a SSL. When contacting them they have said it is a problem inside my ssh_config. but I have no clue how to repair it

Comment: What server software do you run?

Comment: I don't run any server Software I just try to connect simply from the command line : ssh -v <host>